# "[(value)]" doesnt work for kendo-datepicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to add a kendo-datepicker to a angular reactive form. When i set the formControlName, The date set in the [(value)] doesn't appear on the UI.

Sample :
Not working

[image: Not Working Image]

Working

[image: Working Image]

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ooEy0cVJecE3eR6qHcoU?p=preview)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective } from "@angular/forms"
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
    <div class="example-config">
        Selected value is: {{value | kendoDate:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
    </div>
    <div [formGroup]="submitForm" class="example-wrapper" style="min-height: 400px">
        <p>Select a date:</p>
        <kendo-datepicker
            [navigation]="false"
            [(value)]="value"
            formControlName="test"
        ></kendo-datepicker>
        <p>(use Alt+↓ to open the calendar, ← and →  to navigate, ↑ to increment and ↓ to decrement the value)</p>
    </div>
`
})

export class AppComponent {
public value: Date = new Date();
submitForm : FormGroup = new FormGroup ({
    test: new FormControl()
})
}
```

How to set the default value as the above doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: could you share your code and check value field is Date type.

Comment: Working code : "<kendo-datepicker [navigation]="false" [(value)]="value"></kendo-datepicker>". Not working : "<kendo-datepicker [navigation]="false" [(value)]="value" formControlName="test"></kendo-datepicker>".  Value is set as follows: public value: Date = new Date();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you should add the value object to the FormControl construcor, or else it will set it to [undefined](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor()) initially. (I think)

change this:
`test: new FormControl()` to test: `new FormControl(this.value)`

[Working demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SrgyLBto1ZNqZj51VcK1)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div class="example-config">
            Selected value is: {{value | kendoDate:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
        </div>
        <div [formGroup]="submitForm" class="example-wrapper" style="min-height: 400px">
            <p>Select a date:</p>
            <kendo-datepicker
                [navigation]="false"
                [(value)]="value"
                formControlName="test"
            ></kendo-datepicker>
            <p>Value= {{value}}</p>
        </div>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    public value: Date = new Date();
    submitForm : FormGroup = new FormGroup ({
        test: new FormControl(this.value)
    })
}
```

Comment: Apologies. Should have provided with a plunker. I have modified your code to add a formgroup. Kindly find the modified code here 

https://plnkr.co/edit/ooEy0cVJecE3eR6qHcoU?p=preview

Yes. The code is formatted correctly. There is no error in the console.